# заимствованные слова

Tags: этимология

Какие русские слова были заимствованы в другие языки, кроме слова "робот"?

Comment: Вы, наверное, не знаете, что слово "робот" было придумано чешскими братьями Чапеками примерно 100 лет тому, и уже из чешского попало в русский и многие другие языки.

Answer (score 1):

Вот посмотрите, по-моему, копируют друг у друга, откуда - не знаю: https://tiina.livejournal.com/9761977.html

Здесь вроде бы информация больше внушает доверие: 
https://russian7.ru/post/kakie-russkie-slova-pereshli-v-drugie-ya/

> Из русского языка в другие перешел не один десяток лексических единиц.
>   Одну из наиболее обширных групп слов, перешедших из русского в другие
>   языки, составляет лексика, относящаяся к **кулинарии**. Английский
>   язык заимствовал названия знаменитых русских рыб – белуги и севрюги.
>   Этимологические словари английского языка относят заимствование к XVI
>   веку – видимо, тогда, с началом регулярного торгового сотрудничества
>   между странами, англичане «распробовали» эту рыбу и начали поставлять
>   ее в Англию. Сейчас в английском есть и синоним слова «севрюга» -
>   stellate sturgeon. «Белуга» есть и во французском языке – beluga. Этим
>   же словом называют и одну из моделей самолета Airbus. Во многие
>   европейские языки попало и слово «стерлядь» (sterlet). Его иногда
>   считают одним из первых заимствований из русского и полагают, что в
>   английский язык оно вошло уже в XIV веке. «Рыбное» слово из русского
>   языка есть даже в японском – «икура». Оно обозначает только красную
>   икру как блюдо. Для обозначения икры вообще японцы, знающие толк в
>   дарах моря, используют свои слова.
>
> Самый известный пример заимствования из русского во многие языки –
>   слово «водка». Оно есть и в английском, и во французском, и в немецком
>   языках. Причем в немецком водка стала «мужчиной» - слово приобрело
>   артикль мужского рода, der Wodka. А во французском языке есть два
>   слова: «wodka» - для польской и «vodka» - для русской водки. В
>   японском слово «водка» имеет около пяти вариантов написания. Из
>   безалкогольных напитков такую популярность имеет только «квас» – kvas
>   на английском, испанском, португальском и многих других языках. В
>   некоторые из языков это слово вошло, вероятно, через другие славянские
>   языки. Те народы, которые, как и русские, делали квас, часто имеют
>   собственные названия для этого напитка – kali (эст.), gira (лит.).
>   Хлеб и пирожки Соседствовавшие со славянами финно-угорские племена
>   заимствовали из русского не один десяток слов. Сейчас и в финском, и в
>   эстонском языках слова, обозначающие хлеб, перешли от славян: leipä
>   (фин.) и leib (эст). Знакомыми русскому человеку покажутся и слова
>   lusikka (фин.) и lusikas (эст.) – оба они, вероятно, имеют общего
>   предка - слово «ложка». В английском языке существуют и «пирожки» -
>   pirozhki. Правда, есть версия, что это слово попало в язык через
>   посредничество польского, в котором «пирОги» - это, скорее, вареники с
>   разными начинками (иногда жареные). В польском есть и «русские пирОги»
>   (ruskie pierogi) – это вареники с начинкой из смеси творога и
>   картофеля, подающиеся с поджаренным луком, сметаной или шкварками.
>   Слово «пироги» в близком нам значении оказалось в японском языке –
>   «пиросики». Причем взято это слово было сразу во множественном числе,
>   и его эквивалента в единственном нет. Слово «пирожки» вошло и в
>   «домашний» немецкий язык поволжских немцев, приобретя форму birocks
>   или pirogen. Пирожки есть даже в греческом – piroski, но так называют
>   только жареные во фритюре изделия из теста, а не печеные в духовке.
>
> **Бабушки, матрешки, бабалайки и другие символы России**. Если англичанин кого-то назовет babushka, то возможно, он не имеет в виду
>   возраст. Он лишь указывает на способ повязывания платка – узлом под
>   подбородком. Но и привычную нам русскую бабушку в платке в английском
>   языке так тоже можно назвать. С платком, косынкой связано и японское
>   «бабусика». Многие японцы удивляются, когда слышат обращение
>   «бабушка», особенно если бабушка не носит платков. У греков и
>   некоторых других европейских народов, например, испанцев, baboushka -
>   это матрешка. Австралийцы тоже предпочитают такое название. Но вообще
>   в большинстве языков «матрешка» - это matroesjka (голландский),
>   matriochka (французский, наряду с poupée russe), matrjoska
>   (венгерский) и так далее. Интересно финское название maatuska,
>   напоминающее наше слово «матушка». У испанцев также существует
>   подобный вариант – mamushka (в испанском для «матрешки» есть целый ряд
>   обозначений). Не менее популярно слово «самовар» - этот предмет для
>   кипячения воды называют так в большинстве языков (samovar или samowar
>   – это слово почти не подверглось трансформации).
>
> **Экономика и политика.** Как только между странами устанавливаются политические и экономические отношения, появляется необходимость в
>   знании того, какие денежные единицы там в ходу, как называются органы
>   власти, какие административно-территориальные единицы существуют.
>   Английские торговцы, дипломаты и путешественники с XVI века записывали
>   русские слова, которые в дальнейшем употреблялись для описания
>   ситуации в России. В состав этой лексики вошли rouble, copeck
>   (копейка), voivoda (воевода), boyar (боярин). Шведское torg,
>   обозначающее «площадь», произошло от русского «торг» (торговое место),
>   «торговать». Между русскими и норвежскими рыбаками и торговцами в XVII
>   веке даже сложился особый язык – руссенорск, в котором лексика
>   разделялась поровну между русским и норвежским, а грамматика была
>   максимально упрощена. Предложения выглядели примерно так: En voga
>   mokka, så galanna voga treska — «Один воз муки за полвоза трески». В
>   начале XX века он почти исчез, сохранился только на Шпицбергене. Цари
>   и аппаратчики Необычное употребление получило слово tsar. Наряду с
>   обозначением царя как главы Руси в современном английском оно
>   используется как неофициальное название должности человека,
>   ответственного за какой-либо важный участок работы, нечто вроде
>   советника. Даже в американском Белом доме были «tsar’и», правда,
>   бывшему президенту Обаме это слово не нравилось. С течением времени в
>   другие языки переходили «колхоз», «перестройка», «погром», «самиздат»,
>   «нигилист», «аппаратчик», «спецназ», «силовики». В основном они
>   остались кальками, употребляющимися только для характеристики
>   российских реалий. Во французском есть слово bérézina, обозначающее
>   катастрофу, полный провал. Легко можно догадаться, что во французском
>   оно оказалось в 1812 г., когда Наполеон потерпел сокрушительное
>   поражение на берегах реки Березина. Частое во многих статьях слово
>   «спутник» (sputnik), употребляющееся в качестве примера перехода слова
>   в другой язык, в английском не стало обозначением искусственных
>   спутников вообще, а служит названием только того самого советского
>   устройства. Много русских слов перешло в языки народов, которые либо
>   входили в состав Российской империи, а позднее – в Советский Союз,
>   либо «ориентировались» на Россию. Так, в корейском оказались слова
>   «партизан» (палчхисан), «трактор» (тыракторы) и некоторые другие.
>   Сейчас они до сих пор используются в северокорейском варианте. В
>   современный иврит репатрианты принесли множество слов из своих родных
>   языков. Из русского, помимо прочих вошло даже не слово, а морфема –
>   суффикс «ник», обозначающий человека, принадлежащего к какой-нибудь
>   группе, или характеристика человека (киббуцник – житель киббуца,
>   нудник – зануда и т. д.). Сейчас процесс заимствования продолжается -
>   как из иностранных языков в русский, так и наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Послушайте на ютубе ролики на татарском языке, на казахском... ингушей, якутов, болгар, армян, молдаван...
Имейте в виду, что "заимствованное" и "пришлое" - разные понятия. Если в языке понятие названо словом этого языка, то иностранное слово, которое называет это же понятие, является  заимствованным. А если в языке понятие не названо и для его названия взято иностранное слово, то это - пришлое слово.